# How do I get Code Actions for a URL in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

If I have a handle on a `uri` in VS Code, is there a way to get all available code actions for that range? I've tried looking for the it in the docs but could primarily find info about how to register actions, rather than reading them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `vscode.executeCodeActionProvider` command for this:

```ts
let uri = Uri.file('/some/path/to/file');
let codeActions = await commands.executeCommand('vscode.executeCodeActionProvider', uri, range);
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands